# Escaping special characters combinedly at VB code and oracle

Tags: sql, vb.net

In SQL I had to alias my column header with some text containing special character, So to mask these characters {}, I had to keep them in double qoutes.
eg:

```
select column1 as "{Ctrix}" from table;
```

When ran in sql the result is

```
{Ctrix}
-------
1

2

3
```

The problem that I got was while passing the same above query in the code that I had written in VB.

```
strSQL="select column1 as "{Ctrix}" from table;"
```

The query is getting truncated and giving error. Please help me, how to handle this properly at sql/vb... which satisfies both.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes twice:

```
strSQL="select column1 as ""{Ctrix}"" from table;"
```

As you can see above you can escape by doubling them, instead of just `"` use `""`.

Check [String Data Type (Visual Basic) in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwcx436.aspx):

> You must enclose a String literal within quotation marks (" "). If you must include a quotation mark as one of the characters in the string, you use two contiguous quotation marks ("")..